# D3's mouse coordinates relative to parent element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouse, coordinates

I would like to get mouse coordinates relative to parent or any other element in the DOM other than `this` but I keep getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getBoundingClientRect' d3.v3.min.js:1
H d3.v3.min.js:1
vo.mouse d3.v3.min.js:3
(anonymous function) index.html:291
(anonymous function)
```

My code :

```
.on("mouseup", function(d){
    var th = d3.select( this );

    var coordinates = [0, 0];
    coordinates = d3.mouse( d3.select("body") );
    console.log( coordinates[1] );
    console.log( window );
    //th.attr("cy", d3.mouse),
    //d.newY = th.attr("cy");
    console.log(d);
});
```

As far as I have noticed I can only get mouse coordinates relative to element that I have attached `.on("mouseup", ...)` event listener.

Is there a way to get those coordinates relative to other element in the DOM ?

Comment: Did you try using the `offset` methods of jQuery ?

Comment: No, I see that I have to use DOM placeholders like `this` or `this.parentNode` not `jQuery`'s or `D3.js`'s objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use d3.event.pageX and d3.event.pageY. An example where I use this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
        hover.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);
        hover.html(new Date(d.creationDate)+": "+d.reactionTime).style("left", d3.event.pageX+"px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28)+"px");
    });
```

Comment: just curious why `- 28` ?

Comment: @Angular_10 just another magic number :) Also pageX and pageY won't give u a result relative to container.

Answer (score 53):

[d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse) expects a DOM element, not a d3 selection.

```
d3.mouse(d3.select('body').node())
```

Of course selecting the body can be even easier:

```
d3.mouse(document.body)
```

@Tom's answer works also in your case because you want the position relative to the page, but it doesn't work if you want the position relative to some other container.

Say you want to position a popup where the user clicked and you want to position it relative to the svg element so that it pans with the rest of your display.

```
nodeEnter.on('click', function(d){
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(svg.node());
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - lets pretend it was selected.